# How to add multiple images to custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, metabox

I would like to create a simple plugin to add multiple images to a custom post type. I have created a plugin to add a single image to a custom post type, but I am unable to figure out how to add multiple. [image]
this is where I'm at.

js file-

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // add image uploader functionality
        var meta_image_frame;

      $('.meta-image-button').live('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            if( meta_image_frame ){
                wp.media.editor.open();
                return;
            }

            meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
                title: 'Portfolio Image Gallery Selection Window',
                button: {text: 'Add to Gallery'},
                library: { type: 'image'},
                  multiple: false
            });

            meta_image_frame.on('select', function(){
                var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

                   var url = '';

                $('#meta-image').val(media_attachment.url);


            });

            meta_image_frame.open();

      });

      $('#add-input').click(function(event){

            add_input()
        }); 

        function add_input(){


            var input = "<p><label for='meta-image' class=''>Add Project Image</label>"
                              +"<input type='text' name='meta-image' id='meta-image' value='' />"
                              +"<input type='button' class='meta-image-button button' value='Upload Image' />"
                              +"<input type='button' class='meta-image-button button remove-button' value='Remove Image' /></p>";

            $('#images-container').append(input);

        }

}); //end main jquery function
```

this is my php file-

```
    <?php

/*----------------------------------------------------------
                       Create Post Type
------------------------------------------------------------*/

function portfolio_create_post_type(){
    $labels = array(
            'name' => __('Portfolio', 'portfolio'),
            'singular_name' => __('Project', 'portfolio'),
            'add_new' => __('New project', 'portfolio'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add new project', 'portfolio'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit project', 'portfolio'),
            'new_item' => __('New project', 'portfolio'),
            'view_item' => __('View project', 'portfolio'),
            'search_item' => __('Search project', 'portfolio'),
            'not_found' => __('No products Found', 'portfolio'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No products found in trash', 'portfolio')
        );
    $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array(
                    'title',
                    'thumbnail',
                    'editor',
                ),
            'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'category')
        );
    register_post_type('Portfolio', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'portfolio_create_post_type' );


/*----------------------------------------------------------
                       Create Meta Box
------------------------------------------------------------*/


function portfolio_meta_box(){
    add_meta_box( 'portfolio_gallery', 'Project Gallery', 'project_meta_box_cb','Portfolio', 'normal', 'high' );
}//portfolio_meta_box

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'portfolio_meta_box' );

/*----------------------------------------------------------
                  Meta Box Fields
------------------------------------------------------------*/

function project_meta_box_cb(){
                wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'prfx_nonce' );
                $prfx_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );

                ?>
                <div class="wrap">
                <input type="button" id="add-input" value="Add Image">

                <div id="images-container">


                </div><!-- end images container -->
                </div>
                <?php
            }

/*----------------------------------------------------------
                  Save the Data
------------------------------------------------------------*/
function project_meta_save( $post_id ) {

        // Checks save status
        $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
        $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
        $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

        // Exits script depending on save status
        if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
            return;
        }

        // Checks for input and sanitizes/saves if needed
       if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-image' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-image', $_POST[ 'meta-image' ] );

    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'project_meta_save' );

/*----------------------------------------------------------
                  Load Javascript File
------------------------------------------------------------*/
function project_image_enqueue() {
    global $typenow;
    if( $typenow == 'portfolio' ) {
        wp_enqueue_media();

        // Registers and enqueues the required javascript.
        wp_register_script( 'meta-box-image', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'meta-box-image.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_localize_script( 'meta-box-image', 'meta_image');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'meta-box-image' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'project_image_enqueue' );

?>
```

Comment: In order to get a good answer and avoid having your question closed, please be more specific. Include a screenshot of what you want, add code that you've used so far (or that isn't working), and specify more about the image feature you're trying to build. Right now, it's unclear if you're talking about a custom meta box, featured image, image in a post, or something else.

Comment: I added my current progress, I created a custom meta box that appears under my custom post type.

Comment: It would be nice to see a pure PHP answer instead of: "Use this plugin".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be an alternative for you. The [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plug in has an Image Field, which allows images to be uploaded and selected. You can set the field to show on your Custom Post Type pages and also integrate a line of code into your template file. You can create as many image fields as needed. [Learn more about the Image field here.](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Meta Box](https://metabox.io) plugin, which supports various image fields (you can choose from the Media Library or upload image, just like inserting images to the post editor. You can choose either:

- `image_advanced` field which acts like the **Add Media** button of WordPress
- `file_input` which allows you to select an existing image or use an *external* URL for the image
- `plupload_image` which show a placeholder for drag and drop files

Besides, this plugin allows you to **clone** the fields if you want, so you can build the gallery easier.

You can integrate the plugin with any custom post type and create as many fields as you want. Here is the [list of supported fields](https://metabox.io/docs/define-fields).